# PHP performance OS

Tags: php, linux, windows, macos, operating-system

I'm not used to ask question on forum but this one is out of my scope.

Here is my discovery :

- php performances are way different on depending of OS.

**Here is the experiences :**

- I used a brand new Laravel projet from the official documentation (I guess you can do the same with Symfony or even any PHP projet)
- I used a profiler Laravel debugbar (I guess you can use any profiler you want or even browser inspector)
- I deployed the projet on Windows, MacOs and Linux virtual machine (linux VM is hosted by the same PC than the one for the test on Windows)
- I tried with the same PHP configuration
- I disabled windows defender
- I tried with PHP NTS and TS on all machines

**Here are the results :**

- The loading basic page of the dashboard takes around

  - 200ms on Windows
  - 20ms on MacOs
  - 20ms on Linux Virtual machine
- Basical Windows is 10 times slower than the others OS

  - This is related to the performance os the CPU since Linux VM is 10X times faster than Windows on the same machine

**Here is my guess :**

- PHP build are different depending of the OS (of course) and the one for Windows is defensively not as performante as the others (sad story)
- Windows use something on top of PHP that makes it slower.

Here are my questions :

- What is causing that lack of performances on Windows ?
- Is it possible to run PHP faster on Windows ?

Please give constructive answer :

- Windows is bad is not an answer
- Windows use services that slower PHP execution without giving any name of services nor program is not a constructive answer.
- Giving more tests to do to get interring result is a constructive answer.

Thank you for your help

Comment: A test on a single instance of each OS doesn't make for statistically significant evidence

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer can solve your problem. The different file system on Windows and Unix/Linux.

[php window 4~5 times slower in windows than linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38988636/php-window-45-times-slower-in-windows-than-linux)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually yes php function mike is_dir and realpath are way slower on Windows due to it way to manage files.